# Database Design for product prices depending on time of a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm building a food ordering web application with a standard product/category setup - a category (for example Pizza) has many products (Pizza Salami).

```
Category
--------
id
name

Product
-------
id
name
category_id
```

The problem: the price of a category depends on the time of the day. For example for 2pm - 6pm and 9pm - 11pm the price for a pizza is cheaper.

How would I design the prices table and relationships in an effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pricing is predictable, you could put a "base price" attribute in the product table, then read it from code, and calculate the "final price", depending on the time. You'll then store that final price in your orders table.
    But if you want to be able to read tje final price from the database, I sugest you look into your database documentation, for how to create functions and views.